# How to create a JPA repository for Books, Clients, Orders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I am trying to create 3 JPA repositories with 3 according services, but I don't even know how to start. Id appreciate if any of u takes a loot at this.

**The book DTO**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean available;

    protected Book() {}

    public Book(String name, String type, boolean available) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.available = available;
    }
    public Long getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", available=" + available + "]";
    }


}
```

**the Order DTO:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String customerName;
    
    protected Order() {}
    public Order(Integer id, String customerName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", customerName=" + customerName + "]";
    }
}
```

**The client DTO:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private String clientEmail;
     private String clientName;
     
     protected Client() {}

    public Client(String clientEmail, String clientName) {
        super();
        this.clientEmail = clientEmail;
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public String getClientEmail() {
        return clientEmail;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client [clientEmail=" + clientEmail + ", clientName=" + clientName + "]";
    }
     
}
```

**Book repo:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.Book;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

**Order repo:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.Order;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
}
```

**Client repo:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.Client;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {
    Map<String, Client> clients = new HashMap<String, Client>();
}
```

**Book Service:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BookService{
    
}
```

**Order service:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class OrderService {

}
```

**Client Service:**

```
package com.mile.pc.java8.book_api_jpa.DTO.repo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ClientService {

}
```

I know It's a lot to ask. But I'd appreciate it a lot...Thank you :)

Comment: `List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();` etc. should not be part of the repos and I would put `@EnableJpaRepositories` onto a config class or the application. With this setup you already should have basic repository methods and you can add any others you like (think about what might be required and read the docs on the how-to). As for the services: what purpose should they fulfil? What are the requirements for those? Start building methods that meet those requirements and that use the repositories as needed (auto-wire the repos into the services to have them available).

Comment: Model > Dao(@Repository) > Service(@Service) > Controller(@RestController/@Controller) - This is a common design - You missed DAO layer - Import this project, run and debug on your local machine .https://github.com/mehmetpekdemir/Library-Management-System

Comment: Ty Sibin <3.is there a way to commend you for answering, Sibin?